Problems with grid and overflow CSS properties
I am making a web page with HTML and CSS. For its structure I am using grid-layout. The problem is in the tag <main></main>, due to its text is so long and it is not displayed correctly even I use the overflow-y: auto; property.
I notice that increasing <main></main> tag area or reducing the font size, the text displays properly, but it isn't nice solution for my purpose.
How can I display whole text without changing the font size or grid areas?


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}

div.container>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container>header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

div.container>aside:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

div.container>main {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.container>aside:last-of-type {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

div.container>footer {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <aside>Right</aside>
  <main>En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor. Una olla de algo más vaca que carnero, salpicón las más noches, duelos
    y quebrantos los sábados, lentejas los viernes, algún palomino de añadidura los domingos, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda. El resto della concluían sayo de velarte, calzas de velludo para las fiestas con sus pantuflos de lo mismo, los días
    de entre semana se honraba con su vellori de lo más fino. Tenía en su casa una ama que pasaba de los cuarenta, y una sobrina que no llegaba a los veinte, y un mozo de campo y plaza, que así ensillaba el rocín como tomaba la podadera. Frisaba la edad
    de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años, era de complexión recia, seco de carnes, enjuto de rostro; gran madrugador y amigo de la caza. Quieren decir que tenía el sobrenombre de Quijada o Quesada (que en esto hay alguna diferencia en los autores
    que deste caso escriben), aunque por conjeturas verosímiles se deja entender que se llama Quijana; pero esto importa poco a nuestro cuento; basta que en la narración dél no se salga un punto de la verdad.</main>
  <aside>Left</aside>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>




Why not just remove height: 100vh; from the body or change to min-height?

Also, why such a large font size, it's really hard to read like that?

have you try using scale?

How would this be optimal on mobile?
